# Modifying external SVG images using Javascript

Tags: javascript, svg

I have poker game I am writing for Facebook. I have a selection of 52 external SVG images I use to represent the cards in my game.

At the end of the game I would like to show who is the winner by highlighting the SVG image (representing the cards) with a border. I would like to do this by modifying the SVG code via CSS or Javascript to switch on and off the border in the SVG image.

As I would hate to embed 52 images in my HTML code can I please ask if there is a way of achieving this border using external SVG images?

Answer (score 0):

that can be easily achieved through css, for example you can diferentiate between them with a class and put the particular style for that specific svg, you need to search for svg CSS rules that are a little different than 'regular' CSS
for [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/SVG_and_CSS)

You definitively dont need 52 different images

By the way reading again seems easier is just go withregular CSS and wrap the svgs in regular divs, and then just apply the border to them